# Change foreground color of selected text in RichTextBox from context menu

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, richtextbox, attached-properties

My application is having RichTextBox with custom context menu. I am able to get selected text using TextBoxSelectionHelper attached property, However i am not able to set the foreground color (red or green) of that selected text when user clicks "Question" menu item. Below is my work so far in this regard, i am following MVVM patern.

```
<RichTextBox Margin="50" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True"
                ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible"
                AcceptsReturn="True"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                utils:TextBoxSelectionHelper.SelectedText="{Binding Selectedknowlwdge,Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
            <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding KnowledgeText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>
            <RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding MarkQuestion}" Header="_Question">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="CommentQuestionOutline" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding MarkQuestion}" Header="_Answer">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="LightbulbOnOutline" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="{Binding MarkQuestion}" Header="_Clear">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="FormatClear" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="Cut" Header="_Cut">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="ContentCut" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="Copy" Header="_Copy">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="ContentCopy" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
            <MenuItem Command="Paste" Header="_Paste">
                <MenuItem.Icon>
                    <materialDesign:PackIcon  Kind="ContentPaste" />
                </MenuItem.Icon>
            </MenuItem>
        </ContextMenu>
    </RichTextBox.ContextMenu>
</RichTextBox>




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Media;

namespace Test.Utils
{
    public class TextBoxSelectionHelper
    {
        public static string GetSelectedText(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string)obj.GetValue(SelectedTextProperty);
        }

        public static void SetSelectedText(DependencyObject obj, string value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(SelectedTextProperty, value);

        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for SelectedText.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                "SelectedText",
                typeof(string),
                typeof(TextBoxSelectionHelper),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(null, FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault, SelectedTextChanged));

        private static void SelectedTextChanged(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBox tb = obj as RichTextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                if (e.OldValue == null && e.NewValue != null)
                {
                    tb.SelectionChanged += tb_SelectionChanged;
                }
                else if (e.OldValue != null && e.NewValue == null)
                {
                    tb.SelectionChanged -= tb_SelectionChanged;
                }

                string newValue = e.NewValue as string;

                if (newValue != null && newValue != tb.Selection.Text)
                {
                    tb.Selection.Text = newValue as string;


                }
            }
        }

        static void tb_SelectionChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RichTextBox tb = sender as RichTextBox;
            if (tb != null)
            {
                SetSelectedText(tb, tb.Selection.Text);
            }
        }
    }
}



public ICommand MarkQuestion
{
    get { return new RelayCommand(param => QuestionMarker()); }
}

void QuestionMarker()
{
    //here it should change foreground color of selected text to RED.
}



private string _SelectedText="";
public string Selectedknowlwdge
{
    get { return _SelectedText; }
    set
    {
    _SelectedText = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}

private string _KnowledgeText="";
public string KnowledgeText
{
    get { return _KnowledgeText; }
    set
    {
    _KnowledgeText = value;
    OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

RichTextBox doesn't support data binding, so you'll need to either roll your own solution (not a trivial thing to do) or use one out-of-the-box such as [the one from the WPF Toolkit](https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/wiki/RichTextBox).

Comment: Binding is not an issue, i am able to bind using this code. <FlowDocument>
                <Paragraph>
                    <Run Text="{Binding KnowledgeText, Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
                </Paragraph>
            </FlowDocument>

Comment: I guess it depends on exactly what you're trying to do. If you want full control over everything then you're going to need to control the actual document elements via data binding. If it really is just a case of setting the style of the selection text then I think you might get away with setting the `SelectionBrush` property and setting `IsInactiveSelectionHighlightEnabled` to `true`? I think that only sets the background though, which is why I suspect you'll have to go down the whole data-binding route.